# Python3.6 No module named "readability.readability"

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, module, readability

I'm trying to use readability module, but the error below occurs.
How can I be able to user "readability"?

`/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: No module named readability.readability`

the command I did is below.

`python -m readability.readability -u http://www.ndl.go.jp/jp/service/index.html`

Comment: Do you mean this package? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/readability ? have you installed it?

Comment: oh, Ididn't. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the readability package first by executing

```
$ pip install readability
```

Then you can use the module in your code or with your command.

To get a list of your currently installed modules simply type the following command:

```
$ pip list
docutils (0.10)
Jinja2 (2.7.2)
MarkupSafe (0.18)
Pygments (1.6)
Sphinx (1.2.1)
```